# linux aes256 with cbc encryption/decryption library

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, cryptography, aes

Could anyone please give me an example with **encryption/ decryption aes 256 cbc**. I have found the library  crypt.h and unistd.h, but AN example would be really helpfull.

I need a **linux library**. i don't want to encrypt using third party applications

Comment: Example of what exactly do you need? How to use crypt.h or how to implement aes-cbc?

Comment: -1, from the user with name as

Answer (score 3):

The OpenSSL library is installed by default on virtually every Linux system and you can use it to do 256-bit AES encryption with CBC. The OpenSSL documentation is notoriously poor but using [this example](http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36) as a basis, it's not too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cryptpp](http://www.cryptopp.com/).
An example for AES is in the [wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). I hope this is what you want.

Comment: But could you please tell me: **how to** implement AES 256 cbc encrypt decrypt with an existing library in linux ? I need it with an existing library in linux ( no other depecies) and a **short example** of how to implement AES 256 encrypt cbc

Comment: @ella: Sorry I only used crptopp and botan so far. I am not very familiar with linux.

Answer (score 0):

the need is for a library that has a.cpp and a .h file and does not need to be installed on linux. good question. I know mcrypt.h library.